# Is it possible to use Emoji language with Swiftkey 3?

Tags: languages, swiftkey, emoticons

I have and LOVE swiftkey. Is there anyway I type emoji icons with my swiftkey keyboard?

I've tried going to my keyboard settings and adding the Emoji language, but the swiftkey keyboard still doesn't have it (unless I missed it or it was hidden).